# What is the syntax of a obligatory regex element?

Tags: regex

How can I make the parameter after `:` obligatory? I've tried a couple of online web tools but they couldn't help me.

```
^(?<first>.*?):(?<second>.*?)$
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but try this: `^(?<first>.*?):(?<second>.+?)$`

Comment: @Mikatsu provide an example plz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you mean is, you want that part to contain at least one character? In that case, use `.+?` instead of `.*?`. (`*` means "zero or more", `+` means "one or more".) Better yet, write:

```
^(?<first>[^:]*):(?<second>.+)$
```

Comment: @Mikatsu: `.` matches any character (expect a newline, unless single-line mode is enabled). For more details, see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php